# How to pass both context for xcom and parameter to python_callable

Tags: airflow

I want to have a PythonOperator task which will accept an input parameter data_path and randomly select a csv file from the path and pass the randomly selected file to the subsequent task in the DAG.

For the later part (passing the selected file to subsequent task in the DAG), I want to use xcom_push. How do I need to write my callable and operator?

Without the xcom part, my rough is like following:

```
def _select_random_data(**kwargs):
    data_dir = kwargs.get('data_path')
    logger   = kwargs.get('logger')

    if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
        raise RuntimeError('data directory does not exist')

    pattern = f'{data_dir}/*.csv'
    random_filename = random.choice([x for x in glob.glob(pattern) if os.path.isfile(x)])

    logger.info('random file name: {}'.format(random_filename))

    #task_instance = kwargs['task_instance']
    #task_instance.xcom_push(key='file_name', value=random_filename)


 select_file_task = PythonOperator(task_id='select_file',
                                      python_callable=_select_random_data,
                                      provide_context=True,
                                      op_kwargs={
                                          'data_path': 'path1',
                                          'logger': logger,
                                      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make below code work with "airflow tasks test <dag_id> <task_id> <execution_date>" but the same workflow pipeline does not work when I run from webui - in ui, my DAG fails on select_file_task. I don't get any details in the logs.

```python
def _select_file(data_dir, **kwargs):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")

    #LoggingMixin().log.info('input data path: {}'.format(data_dir))
    logger.info('input data path: {}'.format(data_dir))

    if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
        raise RuntimeError('data directory does not exist')

    pattern = f'{data_dir}/*.csv'
    random_filename = random.choice([x for x in glob.glob(pattern) if os.path.isfile(x)])

    logger.info('random file name: {}'.format(random_filename))

    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ti.xcom_push(key='file_name', value=random_filename)


def _print_filename(**kwargs):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")

    ti = kwargs['ti']
    file_name = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='select_file', key='file_name')

    logger.info('selected file name: {}'.format(file_name))

with DAG('test_pipeline',
         default_args=default_args,
         description='A pipeline for experiments',
         schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
         start_date=days_ago(1),
         dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=5)
         ) as dag:

    start_task = DummyOperator(task_id= "start")
    stop_task  = DummyOperator(task_id= "stop" )

    select_file_task = PythonOperator(task_id='select_file',
                                      python_callable=_select_file,
                                      provide_context=True,
                                      op_args=['/vol/algo1/validation_data']
                                      )

    print_file_task = PythonOperator(task_id='print_file',
                                     python_callable=_print_filename,
                                     provide_context=True
                                     )

    start_task >> select_file_task >> print_file_task >> stop_task
```

Comment: It looks to me the issue I was facing is related to dagrun_timeout being very small. Considering that each task is very simple one, I set it to such small number. After increasing it, I don't see any issue.